# very basic recursion in python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have this problem that I can't really solve, I guess it is because I don't really understand recursion...but I have this function that I need to implement.

```
def elements(num, multiplier, add, limiter) -> List[int]:
```

num is a number which you multiply by the multiplier and then add the number add...and you will append the number num untill it is larger than limiter.

for example

```
(5, 3, 1, 20) will give [5, 16] 
(5, 3, 1, 5) will give []
(4, -2, -2, 74) will give [4, -10, 18, -38]
```

I can not use any cycles so no for cycle or while cycle...or anything that contains cycle in it(sum, min, max....and so on)

I wrote this, and I know it is stupid, but I don't really understand how recursion works I guess...that is why I came here because I learn best from code

```
def first_elements(first, multiplier, addend, limit):
    result = []
    if first > limit:
        return []
    multiplied,_,_,_ = first_elements(first * multiplier + addend, multiplier, addend, limit)
    if multiplied > limit:
        return []
    result.append(first)
    result.append(multiplied)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `append the number add until its is larger than the limiter` ?

Comment: You never have to use recursion if you don't want too. Every solution that uses recursion can be written in an iteration as well. :)

Comment: I meant that number can be appended if it is lower than limiter. Sorry if it was written badly. 
I had to use recursion to solve this :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def solve(first, multiplier, addend, limit):
    if limit <= first:
        return []
    return [first] + solve(first * multiplier + addend, multiplier, addend, limit)

print(solve(4, -2, -2, 74))  # prints [4, -10, 18, -38]
```

Comment: Its a homework question no? I don't know if we are supposed to answer them like this.....

Comment: @JasonChia Well, the OP clearly showed a solution, so why not help? It was no dump of a homework question.

Comment: I guess...but it kinda defeats the purpose of understanding how recursive functions work. Perahaps @fafl can explain what went wrong with the Op's code. it was really close.